# Are UIScrollView contentOffsets absolute?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

This is a very simple question, really:

If I tell my `UIScrollView` to set its `contentOffset` to something like `{0, 50}`, then set it to `{0, 100}` a moment later, will its final position be `y = 100`, or `y = 150`?

I'm trying to get it to focus on certain fields in a table, and it's behaving unexpectedly, but I think if I know the answer to the question or whether the offset is absolute or relative, I can piece the rest together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute. [Apple's documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) says, that `contentOffset` is

> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset **from the
>   origin of the scroll view**.

Comment: Perfect, quick and easy. Thankyou. Apologies for not checking that myself, should have done so.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a),

```
setContentOffset:animated:
```

**Sets the offset from the content view’s origin that corresponds to the receiver’s origin.**

```
- (Void) setContentOffset: (CGPoint) contentOffset animated: (BOOL) animated


--where contentOffset==>A point (expressed in points) that is offset from the 
content view’s origin.
```